# Center a View in Android between 2 views

Tags: android-layout

I need to set a view between 2 views. Please see the attached image, please help me.
I tried playing with Relative and Linear Layout, but I didn't get a solution for this.

Comment: Please check the sample image[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dmJrF.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Please give us what you've done so far so that we can help you to understand why you can't achieve this.

There are several ways to do this.

You could for instance go with a FrameLayout that contains your two horizontal views and your centered view (be careful to declare it in this order to appear on top of it) and apply a centered gravity to it